# Time out issue in CouchDB

Tags: nosql, couchdb

My application is a registration application, where a user will fills out a big registration form with 100 fields and submits it.
The way data stored is:

1. A submission document which stores a submissionId, name, email and datetime of submission.
2. Submission value documents, which is nothing but the data of each field field in the registration form.

When a user fills out the registration form and submits it, 1 submission document is created with a submissionId, and each of its fields are stored as a separate submissionValue document with its key having the submissionId, ie, 100 submissionValue documents.
An example submissionValue document is

```
 {
  "_id": "0027ec9c-83d1-45a7-bd2c-ee41f4i5d692/citizenship[0].country_of_birth[0].label/1551683896469",
  "_rev": "1-4fdf63cb121e475d96c160b80a0598de",
  "$doctype": "submissionValue",
  "value": "India"
}
```

Here the first part of the id (0027ec9c-83d1-45a7-bd2c-ee41f4i5d692) is the submissionId, followed by the key name.

I have an Export to CSV feature where I am facing a timeout issue. I have around 10000 registrations in my application. When I click on the Export button, I am passing all the 10000 submissionIds and then for each submissionId I am calling a View to fetch all the submissionValues. Below is the code for the View:

```
   function(doc) {
  if(doc.$doctype == "submissionValue" && doc._id.indexOf("/") > 0) {
    var submissionId = doc._id.split("/")[0]
    emit(submissionId , doc);
  }
}
```

In the above View, I am  returning all the submissionValue documents for each submission, then in the .NET side I am grouping the records based on the submissionId and writing to Excel.

I am getting timeout exception. I don' know if the problem is with the way data is stored in the documents or the view I am trying to fetch the data.

Comment: Can every submission NOT be done with only one document? Why do you need two documents for each submission? I don't get it :(

Comment: I believe it was designed like this because, the list page only  shows few fields and only when clicked on the details all fields are fetched.